# gcc "can't be more simple" program got Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 compile error

Tags: macos, gcc

Before posting this question I've read hundreds of Google search result pages, searching solution of this problem in vain. My program can't be more simple — these are the only 3 files:

**test.h**

```
#ifndef SYMBOL
#define SYMBOL 

#include <stdio.h>

void output(void);

#endif
```

**test.c**

```
#include "test.h"

void output(void)
{
  printf("%s\n", "Hello world");
}
```

**untitled.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

void main()
{
  output();
  return;
}
```

I use terminal and enter the following command to compile:

```
gcc -o aaa untitled.c
```

Output should print the "Hello world", but instead it keeps throwing this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_output", referenced from:
      _main in untitled-00f904.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I spent the whole day searching for solution, tried all the suggestions as possible but none helped.

Something notable: If I change the file included in untitled.c (`#include "test.h"` to `#include "test.c"`), compiler goes without problem.

Can someone please explain to me why, and how to resolve it?

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -g -v` to understand what is going on. Check with `gcc -v` that your  `gcc` is what you believe it is.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_compile", referenced from:
      _main in main-0fc4d1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

that's the output, following a list of invocation

Comment: You should edit your question, not comment it. I'm sure that question has been asked before.

Comment: I've dug all the similar question on this site, tried all the solution in answers but they didn't work :(

Comment: I don't have a Mac (and I hate them), but I am pretty sure it is a common sysadmin issue.

Comment: My (provocative) suggestion. Get rid of MacOSX, and install Linux on your computer.

Comment: Yeah good idea.  Never run decent software again... oh wait...

Comment: Note [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) — the answer for non-Microsoft systems is `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compile and link both source files into the executable; the linker is telling you it cannot find the `output()` function defined in `test.c`:

```
$ gcc -o aaa untitled.c test.c
```

Comment: Hey thank you a lot you saved me from wasting days in vain :D

Comment: By the way, I saw that gcc on other platform can automatically link header files to compile, it means that by using "gcc -o aaa untitled.c" only it can automatically compile test.c.
Typing all the source files to compile may be quite troublesome, is there a shortcut to avoid typing all the source files for the compiler to compile?

Comment: @Merkurial I don't believe that's true and I've never come across it.    Nobody likes typing that stuff on the command line and nobody does as everyone will use a build system, the most common of which is `make`. A build system will automatically compile and link whatever is necessary when a source file changes.  Other build systems exist; for example `scons`.  Alternatively drop the command line and start working with `Xcode`; it's completely free and is the best IDE I've ever used on any platform, including Visual Studio.